# Trying to print elements of an opened file in Python

Tags: python

I would like to open a .txt file using the input function, and then have the elements of the text file displayed in the shell. When I do the code below, it runs with no errors but does not print anything. I have the .txt file in the same folder as this one, and it is titled scores1.txt.

```
filename = input('Please enter the file name: ')
filename = open(filename, 'r')
scores = filename.read()
print(filename.read())
```

Comment: so nothing major with your code but you can either make use of the variable `scores` that you have implemented, or just do a print(filename.read()) without the `scores` both ways should work then.

Comment: *"...and then have the elements of the text file displayed in the shell..."* - Do you mean the contents of the file?

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO! Could you make sure that your question is clear and understandable as well at show examples of input and expected output along with your own attempt.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
print(scores)
```

instead of:

```
print(filename.read())
```

Please refer to **section 7.2.1.Methods of File Objects** of https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string (in text mode) or bytes object (in binary mode). size is an optional numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned; it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory. Otherwise, at most size characters (in text mode) or size bytes (in binary mode) are read and returned. **If the end of the file has been reached, f.read() will return an empty string ('').**

```
f.read()
'This is the entire file.\n'
f.read()
''
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this instead of `print(filename.read())`:

```
print(scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the input filename is correct and it exists on the current dir, otherwise you should provide the full path to the file, i.e.:

```
filename = input('Please enter the file name: ')
with open(filename) as f:
    scores = f.read()
print(scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use print(filename.read()) directly

```
filename = input('Please enter the file name: ')
filename = open(filename, 'r')
print(filename.read())
```

or use like this:

```
 filename = input('Please enter the file name: ')
filename = open(filename, 'r')
scores= filename.read()
print(scores)
```

or

```
filename = input('Please enter the file name: ')
filename = open(filename, 'r')

for data in filename:
    print(data)
```